# How to send data one at a time with ajax asynchronously - Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, synchronous

where I have a function that sends several ajax requests at a time to the server, but I need to transform this request synchronously into sending only one request at a time. The problem is that the synchronous method simply crashes the page and this is bad since the page has several animations. How can I send one request at a time without using the synchronous method?

Answer (score 0):

> Web Workers makes it possible to run a script operation in a background thread separate from the main execution thread of a web application. The advantage of this is that laborious processing can be performed in a separate thread, allowing the main (usually the UI) thread to run without being blocked/slowed down.

Web Workers API might be helpful. You can seperate UI events and other things. [Web Workers API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API)